# Select "Max" records amongs groups of records that share same columns values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns c1, c2, c3 and c4. I have to retrieve rows of records that have max(c3) among records with same c1 and c2, so I write it this way.

```
select * 
  from XXX a 
 where not exists (
           select 1 
             from XXX b 
            where a.c1 = b.c1 
                  and a.c2 = b.c2 
                  and a.c3 > b.c3
        )
```

But my senior said that this is not efficient, as the query will full scan the table twice. What is the better approach for handling the above scenario?

Remarks: I am using Oracle 11g.

Sample Input:

`c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  1  a 
1  1  2  b
1  1  3  c
2  1  1  d
2  1  2  e`

Result:

`c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  3  c
2  1  2  e`

Comment: With same c1 and c2 means c1=c2 right?

Comment: Giving sample input and output may help to clearify the question

Comment: Can you clarify why you are using a self join on the table? Can you please explain the question clearly with some outputs?

Comment: I just add sample input and output which may help explain my problem.

Comment: "same c1 and c2" means two rows of records that have same c1 and c2. It doesn't mean a single row has same c1 and c2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select c1,
       c2,
       c3,
       c4 
From(
  select 
    XXX.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by c1 order by c3 desc) RNum
  from XXX
)x where Rnum=1
```

Check [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af706/5)

Comment: Your SQL did give a right answer. But when I try your solution to my table which has around 1.5 million records. Its performance is even worse then mine.

Comment: @user1664398 - that seems unlikely as it only hits the table once. Perhaps your adaptation of your real query wasn't quite right? Looking at the execution plans of both queries might shed some light.

Comment: Alex, I agree with you. But it may be due to incorrect index built on the table. Anyway, thanks for TechDo's answer.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't it be `partition by c1, c2 order by c3 desc`?

Comment: Yes, you are right and I already correct this when I run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(c3) FROM XXX
WHERE c1=c2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your question.but still what i understand is that you want a better way to find Max c3 column.Please try this-

```
Select Max(c3) from XXXa,XXXb  where a.c1 = b.c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select max(c3)
from table_name
where c1=c2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a group by and using having...

> SELECT C1, 
>          C2, 
>          C3, 
>          Max(C3)  FROM   XXX  GROUP  BY C1, 
>             C2, 
>             C3 HAVING Max(C3) = C3

I haven't ran this on Oracle but I think this is the way to do it.

Hope this helps.